# Text with underline line in Raphael JS

Tags: javascript, raphael

I want to make a simple thinge. Just a text with underline line like  tag in html. How can i do it in Raphael JS?

Comment: Relevant discussion at http://groups.google.com/group/raphaeljs/browse_thread/thread/c42a3d2503fcbbea

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a function that should do what you're after:

```
function underlineText(textElement) {
    var textBBox = textElement.getBBox();
var textUnderline = canvas.path("M"+textBBox.x+" "+(textBBox.y+textBBox.height)+"L"+(textBBox.x+textBBox.width)+" "+(textBBox.y+textBBox.height));  
}

var textElement = canvas.text(100,100,"hello world");
underlineText(textElement);
```

Comment: Just a note on this, it won't work as expected if you've rotated the text. Still, an elegant solution!

Answer (score 5):

Works for SVG canvas, not tested with VML (<=IE8):

```
var text=paper.text(...);
if (text.node){
    $(text.node).css('text-decoration','underline');
}
```

You can set any CSS3 text attribute on an SVG element, and CSS2 attribute on a VML element.

Comment: This is the only answer that works! Thank you. This should be accepted

Answer (score 0):

I think the previous answer is not good anymore (since for me it's not working at all), but with a few tricks I got it working as a charm.

Here it is:

```
var underlineText = function () {
var textBBox = textElement.getBBox();
var textUnderline = paper.path("M"+textBBox.x+" "+(textBBox.y+textBBox.height)+"L"+(textBBox.x+textBBox.width)+" "+(textBBox.y+textBBox.height));};

underlineText(textElement);
```

Cheers!

www.stefanomoscardini.it